# What is causing the program to stop before I can continue with another function?

Tags: c++, string, binary-search

I am working on a binary search for use after this program sorts, and I am unsure of how to stop the crash after it sorts the letters alphabetically.

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "ReadString.h"
#include "SortString.h"
#include "SearchString.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i;
    int column = 500;
    int row = 20;
    char    *inputsearch;

    cout << "How many names will you enter? ";
    cin >> row;

    while (row > 20 || row < 0)
    {
        cout << "Error: Please do not enter more than 20 or less than 0: ";
        cin >> row;
    }

    char **p = ReadString(row, column);

    cout << "Printed: " << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        cout << *(p + i) << endl;
    }

    StringSort(p, row);
    cin >> inputsearch;
    cout << inputsearch;
    SearchString(p, inputsearch);




    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
        delete[] p[i];

    delete[] p;

    return 0;
}
```

Readstring.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

#include "ReadString.h"

using namespace std;

char **ReadString(int row, int column)
{
    char **String = 0;
    int i;
    String = new char *[row];
    int NumChars;

    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
        String[i] = new char[column];

    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter name " << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> String[i];

        NumChars = strlen(String[i]);
    }

    return String;
}
```

Readstring.h

```
    #ifndef READ_STRING_H
#define READ_STRING_H

char **ReadString(int, int);


#endif
```

SortString.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>

#include "SortString.h"

using namespace std;

void StringSort(char **str, int row)
{
    char t[20];
    int i, j, k;

    for (i = 1; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j < row; j++)
        {
            //compare each 
            if (strcmp(str[j - 1], str[j])>0)

            {
                strcpy(t, str[j - 1]);
                strcpy(str[j - 1], str[j]);
                strcpy(str[j], t);
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "Strings (Names) in alphabetical order : \n";
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << str[i] << "\n";
    }
    getch();
}
```

SortString.h

```
#ifndef SORT_STRING_H
#define SORT_STRING_H

void StringSort(char **, int);

#endif
```

SearchString.cpp

```
#include <string.h>

#include "SearchString.h"

int SearchString(char **p, char *inputsearch)
{
    int     First;
    int     Middle;
    int     Last;

    First = 0;
    Last = strlen(*p) - 1;
    do {
        Middle = (First + Last) / 2;
        if (inputsearch == p[Middle])
            return Middle;
        else
            if (inputsearch > p[Middle])
                First = Middle + 1;
            else
                Last = Middle - 1;
    } while (First <= Last);
    return -1;
}
```

SearchString.h

```
#ifndef Search_String_H
#define Search_String_H

int SearchString(char **, char *);

#endif
```

Comment: And when you used your debugger to step through your code, one line at a time, examining the values of all variables, up to the point where your debugger detected the crash, what observations did you make?

Comment: Your buffer sizes are inconsistent. Sometimes it's 500. Sometimes it's 20. I suspect a buffer overflow somewhere. But since you're using C++, you should be using `std::string` and `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

When you do 
    cin >> String[i];
In ReadString.cpp, you don't make sure the input length plus the null terminator is less characters than the array of size 'column' allows. If you type in something with more characters than the width of the column, you'll corrupt your freestore heap.